# elements of sets, subsets relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory

give an example (if possible) such that:

a)$x\in y$ and $x\not\subseteq y$

here I take $x=\{1,2\}$ and $y=\mathcal{P(x)}=\{\emptyset, \{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$ then $x\in y$ but $x\not\subseteq y$ as e.q $1\not\in y$

b)$x\subseteq y$ and $x\not\in y$ here I cannot find any counter example...By definition of subset any element in x must be in y...
is it true?

c)$x\in y$ and $x\subseteq y$

Here I take $x=\emptyset$ and $y=\mathcal{P(x)}=\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ then $x\in y$ and $x\subseteq y$

could someone please check?

Comment: For (b) notice that even though by the definition of the subset any *element* of $x$ must be in $y$, this does not imply that $x$ is in $y$. If you take as $y=\mathcal{P}(\{1,2\})$ (what you are using in (a)) can you find a *subset* of $y$, that is not an element of $y$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answers for (a) and (c) are fine. For (b), remember that $\varnothing\subseteq y$ for any set $y$ whatsoever, so take $x=\varnothing$ and let $y$ be any set that does not have $\varnothing$ as an element, e.g., $\{\{\varnothing\}\}$.

**Added:** For (b) you might also consider the fact that a finite set $y$ has $2^{|y|}$ subsets and $|y|$ elements, and $n<2^n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$. Thus, **every** finite $y$ will give you an example: it has more subsets than elements, so at least one of those subsets cannot be an element. In fact you can always take $x=y$: $y\subseteq y$, but $y\notin y$. If you’re working in $\mathsf{ZF}$ this is true for all $y$ as a consequence of the axiom of regularity (also called foundation), but you can check it explicitly with any simple finite example that you might construct, like your answers to (a) and (c).

Comment: Thank you Brian, you are again right

Comment: @Heidi: You’re welcome. I added a bit that you might find useful at some point.

Comment: @@ Brian: I am going to read it right now. I liked that you referred to ZF and showed me yet another application of the foundation axiom. (Yes we work with ZF)

Comment: I wished I have thought about using the fact that no set can be an element of itself, thanks!

Comment: @Heidi: It does make it easy, doesn’t it? :-) You’re welcome!

Answer (score 4):

$(a)$ and $(c)$ are alright. For $(b)$ let $x=\{1,2\}$ and $y=\{1,2,3\}$, Then $x\subseteq y$ but $x\notin y$. In contrast an example for $x\subseteq y$ but $x\in y$ would be when $x=\{1,2\}$ and $y=\{1,2,\{1,2\}\}$.

Comment: very nicely explained, thank you!